# How to authenticate with jwt when testing a protected route in express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to test a protected route in express using supertest. The following code gives me a 403 error and therefore I can not run any test correctly.

gameRouter.js - the protected route:

```js
router.post(
    '/posts/:id/comments/add-comment',
    verifyToken,
    controller.addCommentToPost
);
```

verifyToken function:

```js
exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (isDataNullOrUndefined(req.headers.authorization)) {
            throwAPIError(401, 'ERR_MISSING_TOKEN', 'Missing token');
        }
        // FORMATTED AS - "BEARER TOKEN.IS.HERE"
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, jwtConfig.secret);
        const userId = decodedToken.userId;

        if (!userId || (req.body.userId && req.body.userId !== userId)) {
            throwAPIError(403, 'ERR_INVALID_TOKEN', 'Invalid token');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        const error = createErrorData(err);
        res.status(error.code).json(error.error);
    }
};
```

The tests for the route:

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
const { describe, it } = require('mocha');

const app = require('../app');

const request = supertest(app);

let token;
describe('Game Tests', () => {
    describe('Add a comment to a post', () => {
        before((done) => {
            request
                .post('/api/users/login')
                .send({
                    email: 'correct@email.com',
                    password: 'SomeGreatPassword',
                })
                .end((err, res) => {
                    token = res.body.token;
                    return done();
                });
        });

        it('should not allow a comment to be made on a non found post', (done) => {
            request
                .post('api/games/posts/-1/comments/add-comment')
                .auth(token, { type: 'Bearer' })
                .expect(404, done);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: req.body.userId && req.body.userId !== userId , i don't see post with payload.

Comment: @AnonyMouze I have tried removing that and it makes no difference during the test.

Comment: did u check userId?  is it the correct value?

Comment: @AnonyMouze Yeah, the token generated is valid (I grabbed it and tested the same route via Postman), which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

please try this and let me know if you facing the same issue.

server - your server (i.e staging/release)
url - your target block/url

```
import request from 'supertest';
import server from 'path/to/your/server';  // if you are checking in localhost
const server = https://urdeployedurl.com; // if you are checking in deployed environment 
async authValidation() { 
const token = 'your token'
const body = 'your data'
const authVerification = await request(server)
      .post(url)
      .set({ Authorization: 'bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
      .send(JSON.stringify(body));
console.log(authVerification.status)
}
```